Printing triangle of stars in java using recursion with restrictions
We are trying to create a triangle of stars using java, but the restrictions are that you cannot use any loops, extra methods, add extra parameters, add extra variables, or even use string methods. The solution seems straight forward, right after you reach the base you start a new recursion from n-1, but the problem is we are not allowed to use an extra variable. Is a solution even possible? If there isn't, there could be an error in the restriction of using an extra variable, although the others should still be taken into consideration.
The base code prints n stars in a line, and the goal is to make it create a triangle (whether it starts from n or 1, although both would be appreciated)
Expected output when n = 4:
****
***
**
*

or
*
**
***
****

Current code looks like this:
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recurse(3);
    }

    public static void recurse(int x) {
        if (x == 0){
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        
        System.out.print("*");
        recurse(x-1);
    }
}


I tried using that solution but the doc considers that as an extra method

Can you show the expected output for n=5 for example?

are the requirements that strict, or did you type out what you recalled from memory? Can you double check if it is like word for word?

Yeah it's supposed to be a challenge question given over speech, there could be a mistake from the doc about using an extra variable, but other than that the requirements are all correct @BIBOOunit

One way is to use a negative x to mean "print * -x times", and a positive x to mean "print triangle of size x".
public static void recurse(int x) {
    if (x == 0){
        return; // base case for both negative and positive numbers
    }
    if (x < 0) { // we should print -x "*"s
        System.out.print("*");
        recurse(x + 1); // i.e. -(-x - 1), one less "*"
        return;
    }
    // to reach this point, x must be positive

    // to print a triangle of size x...
    recurse(-x); // first print x stars...
    System.out.println(); // a new line...
    recurse(x - 1); // then print a smaller triangle
}


Oh dang, that's devious. All I need now is someone to tell me that this was a job interview question. :D

Is there a possibility of starting with one star till n? ie flipping the triangle

@Smartie You can switch the positions of the recurse(-x) and recurse(x - 1) lines, but that would print a leading new line, and not a trailing new line.

this answer is just so peak uoooooooooh. i think if its recurse(x-1); recurse(-x); System.out.println(); it should print in reverse order but with trailing new line.

If you are allowed to perform arithmetic with Math, then maybe you could pass the total number of stars as argument:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;
        recurse(n * (n + 1) / 2); // Number of stars
    }

    public static void recurse(int x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return;
        }
        recurse(x-1);
        System.out.print("*");
        // Check if 1+8*x is a perfect square:
        if (1+8*x == Math.pow(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(1+8*x)), 2)) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

The output will have the "peak" at the top:
*
**
***
****

To have the upside-down output:
    public static void recurse(int x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("*");
        x--;
        // Check if 1+8*x is a perfect square:
        if (1+8*x == Math.pow(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(1+8*x)), 2)) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        recurse(x);
    }

****
***
**
*


This is the solution I want to offer too. The only difference is that my solution doesn't need to use Math library.
